# R: set variables type and levels in a data frame , based on list

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  v1 = sample(c("L1","L2"),5,replace = TRUE), 
  v2 = sample(c("F1","F3"),5,replace = TRUE),
  v3 = sample(seq(1,5),5,replace = T)
)
```

I want (1) to set the type of the variables, based on a named list:

```
typs <- list("v1" = "factor", "v2" = "factor", "v3" = "numeric")
```

and (2) to set the levels of the factor variables:

```
list.levels <-  list("v1" = c("L1","L2","L3"), "v2" = c("F1","F2","F3"))
```

Ideally, I would like to use a generalized approach, that could be applied to data frames with a dynamic number of columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to write your own function to do the cleaning. Here's one possibility

```
fix_data <- function(data, types=NULL, flevels=NULL) {
  if(!is.null(types) && length(types)>0) {
    data[,names(types)] <- Map(function(col, type) {
      if (type=="factor") {
        factor(data[[col]])
      } else if (type=="numeric") {
        as.numeric(data[[col]])
      } else {
        stop(paste("unsupported type:", type))
      }
    }, names(types), types)
  }
  if(!is.null(flevels) && length(flevels)>0) {
    data[,names(flevels)] <- Map(function(col, levels) {
      factor(data[[col]], levels=levels)
    }, names(flevels), flevels)
  }
  data
}
```

And then call it like `fix_data(df, typs, list.levels)`. Note that it returns a new data.frame so you can either overwrite the original or save it to a new variable.

The basic idea is just to loop over the names in your list and do the proper transformation. We use `Map` to iterate over the names and the values in your list.